# Add current stock price without updating

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-sheets-formula

I have used this formula to access current stock prices

```
      =min(GoogleFinance(A1, "PRICE"))
```

My plan is to use a form to insert a stock ticker and record the stock price at the time of entry onto the Google-sheet. The formula I am currently using updates and therefore the price at entry gets lost. Is there a formula that will not update upon entry that will work during times when the stock market is open?

Comment: Have you already reviewed the Google Sheets functions documentation on https://support.google.com/docs?

Comment: I have checked it and it was no help

Comment: GOOGLEFINANCE has several parameters and attributes. Have you tried them?

Comment: I know how to use Google finance, what I don't know is how to store the price for a particular time. For instance if I enter a ticker at 3:00 EST I can get the current price however at 4:00 EST the current price will now change and therefore my price from 3:00 EST is gone. I don't want to have to add them all manually at each time interval.